# Does using the Walkie-talkie (general chat) attract the Ghost?

Tags: phasmophobia

With the new haunts, you cannot have you flashlight out (or any electronics) during a haunt, because it will attract the ghost to you.

So when playing, I started just doing small bursts of the walkie talkie, and if I hear some static, I know it's still haunting.

But thing is, does it attract ghosts to you? You are using an electrical device by doing that. Or, more importantly, if I do it and the ghost is close to one of my teammates, can it attract it to him?

Comment: For those who havent played in a while, a major update last week had this note:  Electronic equipment will now alert the ghost of your position during a hunt (similar to voice). Turn them off before hiding! https://game-updates.info/phasmophobia?108

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess it didn't before, but with an update pushed today, now it does. https://steamcommunity.com/games/739630/announcements/detail/4624626247919023466

> Using the walkie-talkie will now attract the ghost during hunts

With how its written, and I would guess to prevent trolling, that only affects the one turning on their walkie and not those who receive it.

EDIT: Just checked with the Phasmo discord and a moderator confirmed my guess.

Comment: Note that this does not prevent trolling on Nightmare, where the hunt doesn't end when a player dies, but is instead extended by a further 20 seconds. If you're all bunched up together in the same hiding spot and someone turns a device on, it can end with a total party kill.